# iPhone app run in iPad Retina with image Picker but image picker Object is nil

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiimageview, ipad-2

This is iPhone app code but when i run into ipad retina simulator or
 ipad then it's crash the app. i have check many times & i realise 
 the picker object is nil. but it's works good on iPhone simulator . Any one any Idea about this thing.(This app made only iPhone but run in iPad Retina & iPad)

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; // image picker alloc 
imagePicker.delegate = self; // delegate call by self

imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; //Pick image in Library
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; // OPen Library


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info                
{
    imgImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; //Get Orginial Images
    imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((imgImage), 0.9)]; // Jpg image format
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} // pick image from this method
```

Comment: When it crashes, what specifically is the error message displayed in the debugger?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: Image)'

Please Help me if you know this thing.

Comment: What are the contents of the line that it crashes on? Can you provide it (and any surrounding lines, if possible)?

Comment: It might also help for debugging purposes to print out the returned NSDictionary, like so:

NSLog(@"info = %@", info);

Comment: UIImage *myImage =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
I got nil myImage nil. & crash on other line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...This method is called when an image has been chosen from the library or taken from the camera.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Error:- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: Image)'